# Adobe Connect App with Wine 5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, adobe

I need to use Adobe Connect App for meetings. Unfortunately, I cannot use the normal browser "way", but have to use the desktop application from https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/connect-downloads-updates.html to be able to be a moderator of a meeting.

According to Adobe ("Please note that although there is currently no application for Linux, users on Linux (Ubuntu, Red Hat and OpenSUSE)") there is no app for Linux.
Therefore, I installed **Wine 5.0** ob my **Ubuntu 18.04** and downloaded the Adobe Connect app for **Windows**.

Problem: I can start the connect.exe of the app with Wine. However, after entering the URL for the meeting and clicking on "Continue" nothing happens. (It just loads for a long time)

Any suggestions or ideas are really appreciated!

(I saw a similar question ([Adobe connect and ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224580/adobe-connect-and-ubuntu-18-04)) which asks for the app with PlayOnLinux. Since I use Wine without a graphical frontend and this frontend may be the reason why the app crashes on the other question, I opened my question. However, if the app works with PlayOnLinux, my question can probably be closed.)

Comment: According to [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10270) Adobe connect has "Garbage" level of support. You can't run it on linux.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need Wine to connect to Adobe Connect sesssions on Linux. you just need to switch your browser's [user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) from Linux to Windows ... (and preferably open it in Firefox; Works better in my experience.)

1- Install "[User-Agent Switcher and Manager](http://google.com/search?q=User-Agent%20Switcher%20and%20Manager)" or any other "User-Agent switcher" Addon/Extension on your web browser.

2- Switch your browser's User-Agent to a Windows based one.
(e.g. if you are using Firefox on Linux, change it to "Firefox on Windows"; and if you are using Chrome on Linux, change it to "Chrome on Windows".)

[image: User-Agent Switcher and Manager]

Voila, you can now access Adobe Connect sessions through your web browser on Linux, without getting bothered by Adobe about why you don't have the already EOL Flash plugin installed!

Comment: Since I asked the question I a) switch to another distro and b) didn't had to use the app again. So I cannot try out your solution. However, as I stated I needed to use the app to be moderator of a meeting. One cannot be a moderator in the browser app (at least at the time of my question). Therefore you're solution to switch user-agent in the browser is not answering my question. But perhaps it will work now, if the browser app now allows being moderator on browser.

Comment: To share your screen you need to install the Adobe Connect plugin, witch only works on Windows and Mac

Answer (score 1):

Not all apps work with Wine and some work but they are extremely buggy. Don't you have Windows. If you don't your best choice seems to be to try and use a different app for the meetings.

Comment: This is an unhelpful answer. As stated I need to use this app - it's not my decision. Also, don't you think I'd use Windows if I'd had it?